# Append the values of a particular column from a given dataframe to another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframes similar to samples beneath. First df1 has one column, and second has to columns. This is time series data.

```
#First dataFrame
data=('2013-01-01','2013-02-01','2013-03-01')
temperature=(-9,-14,5)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Data":data,"Temperature":temperature})
df1.set_index('Data',inplace=True)

#Second Dataframe
data2=('2013-04-01','2013-05-01','2013-06-01')
temperature2=(9,15,20)
temperature3=(7,19,22)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Data":data,"Temperature":temperature2,"Temperature2":temperature3})
df2.set_index('Data',inplace=True)
```

Both the dataframes have date type indexes. I want to join values from one column of df2 after values of df1, but I do not know how to do it. It is really simple thing in practice but I need to do this in pandas. Couldn't find any solution in the web. New dataframe should like like this

```
df_new
2013-01-01   -9
2013-02-01   -14
2013-03-01    5
2013-04-01    9
2013-05-01    15
2013-06-01    20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pd.concat` function:

```
df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: Thx bb1 but it is not what i want to achieve. My second dataframe consist of two columns. I forgot to mention about it. Using ``` pd.concat ``` simply add to my new df those columns. What i want to do is to place my values beneath existing values in first df.

Comment: Would you like then to edit your question? In the example you gave, both `df1` and `df2` consist of the index and a single column. The `new_df`DataFrame is supposed to consist of rows of `df1` followed by rows of `df2`, and this is what `pd.concat([df1, df2])` does.

Comment: Yeah.. I`ll do it. I forgot to add additional column

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! i Found a solution to my problem. My DataFrames were imported from xlsx files and headers of columns **should have same name**. Then `pd.concat` is working fine ! Thanks !

Problem solved !